# Testing Excel with formula concatenate

Tags: google-sheets

I have test from my college data master
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oQdb.png)

and the question are :

1. focus on row no 1 formula, the rest can be copied from no 1
2. use round for column E, and MOD for column F
3. Next process amount is multiply by 10 if remain not 0
4. Decimal column filled with "." if remain is not zero and iteration on no 1
5. Use concatenate for final result by forming the final result of previous row and result of current row

The result must be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIN2a.png)

what a formula for final result

I have try to answer like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ODP7.png)

with formula =CONCATENATE(ROUND(G$2/$B$2,D2),)

but still not same for expected outcome

Comment: Why don't you try the steps you have?

Comment: i have try answer this question but final result colum not same to result must be

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18n6rH0Jg0RxHTjCZ3KZVapor7v6zWrn-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111688557151374871366&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I have try answer E4 to  g22

Comment: I mean the formula, not external link. Also you want google sheets tag not excel.

Comment: =CONCATENATE(ROUND(G$2/$B$2,D2),)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `I3` use:

```
=JOIN(; E3; H3)
```

in `I4` use:

```
=JOIN(; E$3; H$3; E$4:E4)
```

and drag down...

[image]

Comment: in google sheet its work but in excel does'nt  work

Comment: @AchmadYadi you tagged your question with google sheets tag so this is a google sheets solution

Answer (score 0):

same as my above;

in excel u can use this
in i3

```
=TEXTJOIN("";FALSE;E$3;".")
```

in i4

```
=TEXTJOIN("";FALSE;E$3;".";E$4:E4)
```

E$4 fixed positions and when u drag down the E4 will expand its self to be E5 etc. it's little tricky. i get the same test as u but i not finished yet lol but im very curious about that. thats why i found the trick by my self lol. its take time for me to remember the excel formula

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eil5o.png)